# Sending E-mail Through O365

Tags: vb.net, email, office365

Our company recently migrated from an on-premise mail server (CommunigatePro) to hosted mail through our Office 365 subscription.  Ever since then, I've encountered problems sending e-mail messages to people outside of our organization from my VB.NET applications.  I've found a workaround, but I'm wondering if I'm simply missing something in the configuration that might be causing the issues.

My code for sending a message is pretty standard (obviously obfuscated a bit for posting), but I've had to include a separate function for sending the message via CDO if it fails:

```
Private Function SendFTPSuccessMail() As Boolean
    Dim Email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    Dim MailServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com")
    Dim SenderAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("helpdesk@domain.com", "IT HelpDesk")
    Dim BodyText As String = String.Empty

    With Email
        .From = SenderAddress
        .Bcc.Add(SenderAddress)

        BodyText = "SOME TEXT FOR THE E-MAIL MESSAGE"
        .To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("recipient@recipient.com", "Recipient"))
        .Subject = "MESSAGE SUBJECT"
        .Body = BodyText
    End With

    Try
        MailServer.Send(Email)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim CDOError As String = SendCDOEmail(Email, ex)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDOError) Then
            Dim ExceptionMessage As String = ".NET SEND ERROR: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf

            If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
                ExceptionMessage += ex.InnerException.Message & vbCrLf
            End If

            ExceptionMessage += vbCrLf & CDOError

            MessageBox.Show(ExceptionMessage, "NOTIFICATION E-MAIL FAILED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    Finally
        If Not Email Is Nothing Then
            Email.Dispose()
        End If

        MailServer = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

The `MailServer.Send` method works without error if all of the recipients are within the same (my) domain, but will throw an `SmtpFailedRecipientException` or `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` for any recipient address with a different domain.  The `SendCDOEmail` function is as follows:

```
Option Strict Off    

Public Function SendCDOEmail(ByRef OriginalMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage, ByVal OriginalException As Exception) As String
    Dim ErrorMessage As String = String.Empty

    If TypeOf (OriginalException) Is System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException Then
        Dim SMTPEX As System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException = CType(OriginalException, System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException)
        Dim FailedAddresses As New List(Of String)
        Dim NewTo As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        Dim NewCC As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        Dim NewBCC As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)

        For Each InnerEx As System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException In SMTPEX.InnerExceptions
            FailedAddresses.Add(InnerEx.FailedRecipient.ToString.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", ""))
        Next

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.To
            For Each KeepAddress As String In FailedAddresses
                If Recipient.Address = KeepAddress Then
                    NewTo.Add(Recipient)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        OriginalMessage.To.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewTo
            OriginalMessage.To.Add(Recipient)
        Next

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.CC
            For Each KeepAddress As String In FailedAddresses
                If Recipient.Address = KeepAddress Then
                    NewCC.Add(Recipient)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        OriginalMessage.CC.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewCC
            OriginalMessage.CC.Add(Recipient)
        Next

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.Bcc
            For Each KeepAddress As String In FailedAddresses
                If Recipient.Address = KeepAddress Then
                    NewBCC.Add(Recipient)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        OriginalMessage.Bcc.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewBCC
            OriginalMessage.Bcc.Add(Recipient)
        Next
    ElseIf TypeOf (OriginalException) Is System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException Then
        Dim SMTPEX As SmtpFailedRecipientException = CType(OriginalException, SmtpFailedRecipientException)
        Dim NewTo As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        Dim NewCC As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        Dim NewBCC As New List(Of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        Dim FailedAddress As String = SMTPEX.FailedRecipient.ToString.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "")

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.To
            If Recipient.Address = FailedAddress Then
                NewTo.Add(Recipient)
            End If
        Next

        OriginalMessage.To.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewTo
            OriginalMessage.To.Add(Recipient)
        Next

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.CC
            If Recipient.Address = FailedAddress Then
                NewCC.Add(Recipient)
            End If
        Next

        OriginalMessage.CC.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewCC
            OriginalMessage.CC.Add(Recipient)
        Next

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In OriginalMessage.Bcc
            If Recipient.Address = FailedAddress Then
                NewBCC.Add(Recipient)
            End If
        Next

        OriginalMessage.Bcc.Clear()

        For Each Recipient As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In NewBCC
            OriginalMessage.Bcc.Add(Recipient)
        Next
    End If

    Dim CDOMessage As Object = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With CDOMessage.Configuration.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myemailaddress@domain.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"

        .Update()
    End With

    With OriginalMessage
        CDOMessage.Subject = .Subject
        CDOMessage.From = .From.DisplayName & " <" & .From.Address & ">"

        For Each ToAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In .To
            CDOMessage.To = CDOMessage.To & ToAddress.DisplayName & " <" & ToAddress.Address & ">; "
        Next

        For Each ToAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In .CC
            CDOMessage.CC = CDOMessage.CC & ToAddress.DisplayName & " <" & ToAddress.Address & ">; "
        Next

        For Each ToAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress In .Bcc
            CDOMessage.BCC = CDOMessage.BCC & ToAddress.DisplayName & " <" & ToAddress.Address & ">; "
        Next

        Dim FileNames = .Attachments.[Select](Function(a) a.ContentStream).OfType(Of System.IO.FileStream)().[Select](Function(fs) fs.Name)

        For Each File As String In FileNames
            CDOMessage.AddAttachment(File)
        Next

        CDOMessage.TextBody = .Body

        Try
            CDOMessage.Send()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMessage = "CDO SEND ERROR: " & ex.Message
        Finally
            CDOMessage = Nothing
        End Try
    End With

    Return ErrorMessage
End Function
```

This seems to work pretty much every time, but I can't help wondering if there's a way that I can totally avoid using the CDO send method.  I've tried it with both the `domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` and the `smtp.office365.com` server addresses for the `SmtpClient` object, as well as creating a new `Credentials` object and putting the same username/password as I use for the CDO sending method.  Any ideas as to how I can get the `System.Net.Mail` objects to work without having to resort to old-school CDO?

**EDIT:** For the sake of clarification and completeness, I ran another test of the function where I attempted to send a message to one of my Google-hosted e-mail accounts outside of this domain.  This time, I again manually set the `Credentials` property for the `SmtpClient` object in the Try/Catch block of my main mailing function as follows:

```
Try
    MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemailaddress@domain.com", "mypassword")
    MailServer.Send(Email)
    Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim CDOError As String = SendCDOEmail(Email, ex)
    [...]
Finally
    If Not Email Is Nothing Then
        Email.Dispose()
    End If

    MailServer = Nothing
End Try
```

To minimize the number of variables as much as possible, I copied and pasted the username/password information directly from the CDO sending method.  These credentials are for my e-mail account, which is an O365 admin account for our company.  Unfortunately, the test still failed with the exact same `SmtpFailedRecipientException`. The server response given is:

*"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.64 TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied [SN1NAM01FT060.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com]"*

Personally, I'd like to get rid of using my credentials for the mail server anyway by setting up some sort of "generic" login, or implementing some method that would allow "anonymous" sending from my network only, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Regardless, I'm simply not sure what I'm missing.  Maybe it's a setting in my Exchange configuration, or some other "quirk" I'm overlooking.  Thank you for your help.

**One other thing to note:** I did some additional testing with a number of different configurations.  *IF* I changed the `SmtpClient` host to `smtp.office365.com` *AND* set the port to `587` (or `25`), *AND* set the `EnableSsl` property to `True` *AND* explicitly provided user credentials (which is the main thing I was trying to get away from), I was able to get a message to go through without it hitting the `Catch` block and using the `SendCDOEmail` method (which, as noted above, uses explicitly defined credentials).

```
Dim MailServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com")
[...]
With MailServer
    .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemailaddress@domain.com", "mypassword")
    .Port = 587 'or 25
    .EnableSsl = True
    .Send(Email)
End With
```

While this method technically works, I'm really trying to get away from explicitly assigning the credentials in my application, especially since I don't have a "generic" user account on the Exchange server that I can use.  That was the purpose of using the `domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` for the `SmtpClient` host name.  The problem is that I *still* have to provide credentials for the CDO sending method (with `smtp.office365.com` for the host name), so nothing really gets resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suspected, the issue was apparently caused by an Exchange configuration.  I ended up configuring a "connector" to send mail using the Office 365 SMTP relay as outlined on Microsoft's [Office Support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#option3).  Once I set up the relay connector and put in the SPF record, I tested again by sending to my hosted Gmail account *without* providing any credentials or setting any additional settings for the `SmtpClient` object.  The first time I tried, the configuration had apparently not fully gone into effect, but I waited a couple of minutes and tried again.  This time, everything went through without hitting my `Catch` block, and my message showed up correctly in my Gmail Inbox.

I am, however, apparently having some issues with some messages from my multi-function devices now getting caught in the spam filter, even though I updated the SPF record.  I'm hoping that this is just because the DNS hasn't fully propagated yet, but, since I made the change in the O365 admin control panel, I'm not 100% sure about that yet.  I'm going to wait a couple of hours to see what happens.

Here is a run-down of the steps I used to get it working for me (taken directly from their page with some minor edits for clarification, grammar, and formatting):

1. Obtain the public (static) IP address from which the device or application will be sending mail. ***A dynamic IP address isn’t supported or allowed.*** You can share your static IP address with other devices and users, but don't share the IP address with anyone outside of your company. Make a note of this IP address to use in **steps 7b & 8** below.
2. [Sign in to Office 365](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=402333).
3. Select **Domains**. Make sure your domain (e.g., `contoso.com`) is selected. Click **Manage DNS** and find the MX record. The MX record will have a **POINTS TO ADDRESS** value that looks similar to `cohowineinc-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` as depicted in the following screenshot. Make a note of the MX record **POINTS TO ADDRESS** value. You'll need this for **step 9** below.
   [image: Make a note of the MX record Points to address value.]
4. Check that the domains to which the application or device will send have been verified. *If the domain is not verified, emails could be lost, and you won’t be able to track them with the Exchange Online message trace tool.*
5. In Office 365, click **Admin**, and then click **Exchange** to go to the Exchange admin center (EAC).
6. In the Exchange admin center, click **mail flow**, and click **connectors**.
7. Check the list of connectors set up for your organization. If there is no connector listed from your organization's email server to Office 365, create one.

   a. To start the wizard, click the plus symbol (**+**). On the first screen, choose the options that are depicted in the following screenshot:
   [image: Choose "From your organization's email server" to "Office 365"]
   Click **Next** and give the connector a name.

   b. On the next screen, choose the option labeled "***By verifying that the IP address of the sending server matches one of these IP addresses that belong to your organization***", and add the IP address from **step 1**.

   c. Leave all the other fields with their default values, and click **Save**.
8. Now that you are done with configuring your Office 365 settings, go to your domain registrar’s website to update your DNS records. Edit your **SPF record**. *If you do not already have an SPF record, you will need to create one.* Include the IP address that you noted in **step 1** above. The finished string should look similar to this:
      **`v=spf1 ip4:###.###.###.### include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all`**   
   Where `###.###.###.###` is your public IP address from **step 1**. ***Skipping this step can cause email to be sent to recipients’ junk mail folders.***
9. Finally, on the device or in the application from which you are trying to send mail, locate the setting for the mail server and enter the **POINTS TO ADDRESS** value from the MX record you recorded in **step 3**. Because each device and application is different, this setting may be labeled as the `Mail Server`, `SMTP Server`, `Smart Host`, simply `Server`, or something else entirely. You may need to refer to the device or application's documentation to find the appropriate setting.
10. To test the configuration, send a test email from your device or application, and confirm that it was received by the recipient.

**EDIT:** It looks like the issue with the messages getting caught in the spam filter *WAS* due to the DNS not being fully propagated.  After waiting a little over 24 hours, I haven't seen any of the messages from my internal systems getting quarantined.

BTW, for full disclosure, we have a CNAME (alias) record for `mail.domain` on our internal DNS server that points to `domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` to make my programming a touch easier.  This CNAME record doesn't propagate to public DNS servers and is only used by our internal network (hence the exclusion of the `.com` part).  I already had so much code that was written to use the `mail.domain` address for the SMTP server that it was just easier to set up the DNS to handle a quick translation and redirect it to Microsoft's servers.  In my example code in the above question, I replaced the address with the Microsoft server address to keep from confusing the issue any further, but my code actually looks like this:

```
Private Function SendFTPSuccessMail() As Boolean
    Dim Email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    Dim MailServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.domain")
    Dim SenderAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("helpdesk@domain.com", "IT HelpDesk")
    Dim BodyText As String = String.Empty

    With Email
        .From = SenderAddress
        .Bcc.Add(SenderAddress)

        BodyText = "SOME TEXT FOR THE E-MAIL MESSAGE"
        .To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("recipient@recipient.com", "Recipient"))
        .Subject = "MESSAGE SUBJECT"
        .Body = BodyText
    End With

    Try
        MailServer.Send(Email)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim CDOError As String = SendCDOEmail(Email, ex)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDOError) Then
            Dim ExceptionMessage As String = ".NET SEND ERROR: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf

            If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
                ExceptionMessage += ex.InnerException.Message & vbCrLf
            End If

            ExceptionMessage += vbCrLf & CDOError

            MessageBox.Show(ExceptionMessage, "NOTIFICATION E-MAIL FAILED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    Finally
        If Not Email Is Nothing Then
            Email.Dispose()
        End If

        MailServer = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

It looks like I should be able to get rid of the CDO sending method now, but I'm leaving it in for now as a "failsafe".  Once I've had this running successfully for a while, I'll probably remove it completely so I can finally achieve my goal of getting rid of the explicitly defined user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a username and password to `domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com`. It does not accept anonymous messages for recipients external to your Exchange Online organization.

```
MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but you may have missed the part in my original post where I stated that I've tried that as well, without success. When I get into the office tomorrow morning, I'll update my question with more details on the exception I get using the `Credentials` property.